# How apps respond to drag and drop on OSX

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop

Suppose I want to create an app that responds to drag and drop from the dock.  Essentially, suppose I drag a .pdf from my desktop onto the app that is sitting in the dock.  What functionality is there for receiving that action and reacting to it?

Comment: you can see the sample app here.. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageKitDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004371

Answer (score 1):

In the App Delegate:

```
- (void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames
```

Of course this is needed as well:[image]